# How to assign min of uint32_t::max and uint64_t in type safe manner?

Tags: c++

I want to assign minimum of difference of two uint64_t numbers and maximum numerical limit of uint32_t in type safe manner. Is there a way to do it?

```
uint32_t max32 = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
uint64_t a, b;

uint32_t minValue = std::min(max32, b - a);
                               ^^^^^^ (Parameter mismatch warning)
```

Basically. if the difference between a and b is greater than maximum value of uint32_t, I want to use the max value else I want to use the difference. I need to use `minValue` in an API that only accepts uint32_t.

Comment: Declare `max32` as a `constexpr uint64_t`. Then, `static_cast` the result of `std::min` into your `uint32_t min`.

Comment: `uint32_t min = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::min<uint64_t>(max32, b - a));` Something like that, perhaps.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Except don't explicitly specify the template parameters on standard library functions, unless required to (e.g. `std::make_shared`). The standard is liable to change the exact template argument in the future (see [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)).

Comment: @Justin: specifying `<uint64_t>` it is a common and reasonable choice in this case, as `min` requires both arguments to be of the same type for automatic deduction to work, and they're not: we're calling with a `uint32_t` and a `uint64_t` expression.  Using `min<uint64_t>` will cause the first argument to be promoted to `uint64_t` before `min` is called.  That said, my answer shows another way which is a little safer: if some years hence `a` and `b` were changed to say `float`s, the call to `min` wouldn't compile and the programmer would have to rethink things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
minValue = static_cast<uint32_t>(
               std::min(static_cast<uint64_t>(max32),
                        a < b ? b - a : a - b));
```

The `static_cast` creates a 64-bit unsigned value from `max32` to match the type of the diff of `a` and `b`.

Note that when you subtract a larger unsigned number from a smaller one, the result will wrap around - often to some very large number.  For example, `(uint8_t)2 - (uint8_t)3` will yield 255.  That's why I use the `?`/`:` logic to work out which way around to perform the subtraction.